How do I write a test for a specific server (nginx) for Drupal.org?
I'm trying to write a test for Only show the error “Public files directory Not fully protected” for Apache servers.  This is a bug that only appears if running Drupal on nginx, not Apache.
Normally, when I test my own code, the server is whatever type of server I am testing; there is no way to specify a server.
Does the Drupal.org testing infrastructure have a way to test with a specific type of server?  If so, how can I do that?

I tend to avoid mocks where possible, but I wonder if this is a situation where it would make sense to mock the request object and directly set SERVER_SOFTWARE.

I don’t think you really can. That issue is an improvement to https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1559116 but you actually want to test it. Nginx support in Drupal is so weird. There are requirements instructions and issues like https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2937161 but AFAIK it isn’t “really” supported, like Windows, because it isn’t a tested platform. And I can’t find an “Officially support nginx” issue that includes all that would mean.

All the services used by GitLab CI in a Drupal project / issue fork are defined in the .gitlab-ci.yml file the project repository or the issue fork contains. That file usually includes the includes/include.drupalci.main.yml file which contains the following service definitions.
.with-database: &with-database
  name: $_CONFIG_DOCKERHUB_ROOT/$_TARGET_DB_TYPE-$_TARGET_DB_VERSION:$_TARGET_DB_IMAGE_TAG
  alias: database

.with-chrome: &with-chrome
  name: $_CONFIG_DOCKERHUB_ROOT/$_TARGET_CHROMEDRIVER:$_TARGET_CHROMEDRIVER_TAG
  alias: chrome
  entrypoint:
    - chromedriver
    - "--no-sandbox"
    - "--log-path=/tmp/chromedriver.log"
    - "--verbose"
    - "--whitelisted-ips="

default:
  interruptible: true
  image:
    name: $_CONFIG_DOCKERHUB_ROOT/php-$_TARGET_PHP-apache:$_TARGET_PHP_IMAGE_TAG
  retry:
    max: 2
    when:
      - unknown_failure
      - api_failure
      - stuck_or_timeout_failure
      - runner_system_failure
      - scheduler_failure

Those services are created from DockerHub images whose namespace is drupalci (the value of $_CONFIG_DOCKERHUB_ROOT).
Supposing that you could use a different namespace for the DockerHub images, then it would be possible to run all the tests on nginx, but that would require changing the content of the .gitlab-ci.yml file used in the issue fork.
The issue fork for Only show the error “Public files directory Not fully protected” for Apache servers does not contain that file. If it were added, GitLab would complain about conflicts between the issue fork and the project repository (Drupal core, in this case).
